# One hundred and one translations

Tags: cipher, pattern

> Miss Florida,
>   Silver tuxedo,
>   Cadillac moon,
>   Room 101.

What may a doctor provide?

Comment: Good one @Tom. Makes you think

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have

> MS FL
>  AG DJ
>  GM IO
>  WC CI

(I am not sure I have correctly identified the room but it seems somewhat plausible). Here

> each digraph consists of a letter followed by the letter 6 places further on in the alphabet (wrapping round in the obvious way as required).

So a doctor might provide ...

> an RX or prescription, since X=R+6.

Comment: Room could be rot13(YE - yvivat ebbz).

Comment: @LannyStrack, nice alternative!